# How to pass pre-defined functions as a parameter of another function?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have two classes: `TextElement` that is a selenium extension with some text properties (Text returns the string of the element) and the other is `ArrayTextElement` that basically is an array of `TextElement` objects.

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the first element that matches the text
/// </summary>
public static TextElement Find(this ArrayTextElement<TextElement > list, string text)
{
    try
    {
        return list.Items.First(item => item.Text.Equals(text));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException($"Requested element with text: '{text}' wasn't found.");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Finds the first element that contains the text
/// </summary>
public static TextElement FindByContains(this ArrayTextElement<TextElement > list, string text)
{
    try
    {
        return list.Items.First(item => item.Text.Contains(text));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException($"Requested element with text: '{text}' wasn't found.");
    }
}
```

The real issue is that I need to unify those 2 functions into 1. So I want to send the `Equals` and `Contains` functions that extend from String, as a parameter.

Comment: The same way [First() does it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_First__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__).

Comment: yeah, but I need to use Equals strictly for some cases and sometimes I use Contains

Comment: Have you succeeded in doing that with First()? I can see that you have, because you included that code in your question. You are passing two different pre-defined functions as parameters to First().

Comment: I do use First as a method, both functions work, I just need to unify them into one

Comment: You call First() in two different places in your question. Can you identify what kind of things you are passing as parameters to First() in those two places? What is `item => item.Text.Contains(text)`? `item => item.Text.Contains(text)` is a pre-defined function, which you are passing as a parameter to another function.

Comment: yes, they are 2 different functions. One finds an element using Equals and the other uses Contains. The Text property returns the text of the element, which in my case is a Selenium extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor both methods into one by passing a `Func<string, bool>` and using that function inside your first. So what you have now becomes:

```
public static TextElement Find(this ArrayTextElement<TextElement> list, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    try
    {
        return list.Items.First(item => predicate(item.Text));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException($"Requested element with text: '{text}' wasn't found.");
    }
}
```

And to call it with either `Contains` or `Equals` you would do this:

```
public void UsingTheMethod()
{
    ArrayTextElement<TextElement> list = new ArrayTextElement<TextElement>();
    string someText = string.Empty;
    Find(list, s => s.Equals(someText));
    Find(list, s => s.Contains(someText));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass a `Func<string, bool>` like so:

```
public static TextElement Find(this ArrayTextElement<TextElement> list, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    try
    {
        return list.Items.First(item => predicate(item.Text));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException($"Requested element with text: '{text}' wasn't found.");
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var text = // whatever;
var element = elements.Find(s => s.Equals(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can pass an additional parameter to indicate if you want to use an exact match or a partial. The following is good if you the only searches you want to do are exact or partial. The other answers given here are far more versatile, but this version is a little easier to maintain.

```
public static TextElement Find(this ArrayTextElement<TextElement> list, string text, bool exactMatch)
{
    try
    {
        return list.Items.First(item => exactMatch ? 
            item.Text.Equals(text) :
            item.Text.Contains(text)
         );
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException($"Requested element with text: '{text}' wasn't found.");
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
TextElement textElem = list.Find("abcdef", [true|false]);
```

Comment: And how would you call it?

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to work for two cases only because of the boolean parameter, so I'm going to use the accepted answer

Comment: Yes, that's true, as I explained. If you only need to check Equals or Contains, this is easier to maintain.